# define quarter columns with conditions

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follow:

```
ID Mois Year
A   12   2010
B   01   2011
C   04   2010
D   05   2011
E   07   2011
F   11    2010
G   12    2011
H   03    2010
I   01    2012
J   02    2012
```

I wouls like to add quarter columns as:

> quarter1: ( 12(of n-1), 01 of n, 02 of n): means (12 of 2010, 01 of
>   2011, 02 of 2011)
>
> quarter2:(03 of n , 04 of n, 05 of n)
>
> quarter3: (06 of n, O7 of n, O8of n)
>
> quarter4:( 09of n, 10 of n, 11
>   of n)

I have tried this code `

```
data=cbind(data, quarter=ifelse(data$mois==c(12,1,2), "1",
                            ifelse(data$mois==c(3,4,5),"2",
                                   ifelse(data$mois==c(6,7,8),"3", "4"))))
```

but it does not work and i dont know how to add the condition of the quarter1 as( 12(of n-1), 01 of n, 02 of n): means (12 of 2010, 01 of 2011, 02 of 2011)

or can we replace `data$year` where `data$month == 12` to `year + 1`, before doing the quarter?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `data$mois==c(12,1,2)` try `data$mois %in% c(12,1,2)`. And note that R is case sensitive, `Mois` and `mois` are **not** the same thing. (And surely not `Month`.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas yes sure thank you, it's just i wrote it in french so i've forgot to edit it. do you have any idea for the second part replace data$year where data$month == 12 to year - 1?

Comment: Generally, you should ask one question at a time. One way for the second part would be `data$year = data$year - (data$month == 12)`, I guess.

Comment: @Frank thank you for your response but that does not wok, actually this is my main question as i said, can we replace data$year where data$month == 12 to year + 1, before doing the quarter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option could be using the same line of solution as that of OP. Add `quarter` column using `ifelse` and then modify `year` using `ifelse` too.

```
data$quarter <- ifelse(data$Mois %in% c(12,1,2), "1",
                       ifelse(data$Mois %in% c(3,4,5),"2",
                              ifelse(data$Mois %in% c(6,7,8),"3", "4")))

data$Year <- ifelse(data$Mois == 12, data$Year + 1, data$Year)

data
   ID Mois Year quarter
1   A   12 2011       1
2   B    1 2011       1
3   C    4 2010       2
4   D    5 2011       2
5   E    7 2011       3
6   F   11 2010       4
7   G   12 2012       1
8   H    3 2010       2
9   I    1 2012       1
10  J    2 2012       1
```

**Data:**

```
data <- read.table(text = "ID Mois Year
A   12   2010
B   01   2011
C   04   2010
D   05   2011
E   07   2011
F   11    2010
G   12    2011
H   03    2010
I   01    2012
J   02    2012", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactor = FALSE)
```

Comment: thank you @MKR but while doing the "data$Year <- ifelse(data$Mois == 12, data$Year + 1, data$Year)" i've got this error data$year+ 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator , i've done data$year=trimws(as.numeric(data$year)) but i've got the same error again

Comment: @Maha Please check case-sensitiveness for year. Seems you are using `Year` as `year`. I my dataframe its `Year`.

Comment: yes i've noticed it and run it again but remain the same error

Comment: @Maha I have added my the `data` used in my solution. Give it a try. Otherwise try restarting `RStudio`.

Answer (score 4):

**1) formula**  We can use this formula to calculate quarters:

```
transform(data, YearQ = Year + (Mois == 12), Quarter = Mois %% 12 %/% 3 + 1)
```

giving:

```
   ID Mois Year YearQ Quarter
1   A   12 2010  2011       1
2   B    1 2011  2011       1
3   C    4 2010  2010       2
4   D    5 2011  2011       2
5   E    7 2011  2011       3
6   F   11 2010  2010       4
7   G   12 2011  2012       1
8   H    3 2010  2010       2
9   I    1 2012  2012       1
10  J    2 2012  2012       1
```

**2) yearqtr** Another possibility is to use `"yearqtr"` class giving the same result:

```
library(zoo)

transform(data, YearQ = Year + (Mois == 12), Quarter = cycle(as.yearqtr(Year + Mois/12)))
```

giving same as (1).

**2a)** Alternately we may just wish to create yearmon and yearqtr columns:

```
transform(data, ym = as.yearmon(Year + (Mois -1)/12), yq = as.yearqtr(Year + Mois/12))
```

giving:

```
   ID Mois Year       ym      yq
1   A   12 2010 Dec 2010 2011 Q1
2   B    1 2011 Jan 2011 2011 Q1
3   C    4 2010 Apr 2010 2010 Q2
4   D    5 2011 May 2011 2011 Q2
5   E    7 2011 Jul 2011 2011 Q3
6   F   11 2010 Nov 2010 2010 Q4
7   G   12 2011 Dec 2011 2012 Q1
8   H    3 2010 Mar 2010 2010 Q2
9   I    1 2012 Jan 2012 2012 Q1
10  J    2 2012 Feb 2012 2012 Q1
```

**3) switch**  We can use `switch` like this:

```
transform(data, YearQ = Year + (Mois == 12), 
                Quarter = sapply(Mois, switch, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1)))
```

giving same as (1).

### Note

The input `data` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
ID Mois Year
A   12   2010
B   01   2011
C   04   2010
D   05   2011
E   07   2011
F   11    2010
G   12    2011
H   03    2010
I   01    2012
J   02    2012"
data <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: @G.Gronthendieck thank you for your response, but how can i do for this part " replace data$year where data$month == 12 to year + 1 "

Comment: See revised version.

Answer (score 3):

If you can do with the new column `quarter` of class `factor`, then `cut` will do it.

```
m <- data$Mois
m[m == 12] <- 0
data$quarter <- cut(m, breaks = c(-1, 2, 5, 8, 11), labels = as.character(1:4))
rm(m)    # tidy up
```

If you really need or want class `character`, just coerce it.

```
data$quarter <- as.character(data$quarter)
```

**DATA.**

```
dput(data)
structure(list(ID = structure(1:10, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), class = "factor"), Mois = c(12L, 
1L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 3L, 1L, 2L), Year = c(2010L, 2011L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2010L, 2011L, 2010L, 2012L, 2012L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Mois", "Year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```